# How can I start an interactive session (desktop) in the background?

Tags: windows-10, automation, automatic-logon, autologon

**Question:**

How can I start an **interactive** session (desktop) in the **background** using e.g. `psexec` or similar tools ? I would like to later connect to this session using `tscon.exe`

**Background information:**

We got very special security and legal requirements to run an application why I am forced to build such a construct. So please don't question this approach.

And also please note, I can't use `AutoLogon.exe`, as we are forced to use the GPO security setting `Interactive logon: Mesage title for users attempting to logon` and others which prevents `AutoLogon.exe` to work properly.

**The idea:**

- Domain User A logs on to a machine
- User A starts a script
- This script creates an interactive session using a local user in the background
- Instead of the default user shell (`explorer.exe`) some other application (`app.exe`) gets loaded upon logon (also in the background)
- The script calls `tscon.exe`to connect to this session
- The person (technical user a) hands the device over to a customer, which uses and later closes `app.exe` which should lead to a logoff
- Domain User A logs back in and continues normal work

Comment: I don't really see why you would need an interactive session in the first place if the user terminates it anyway. Just let him run it or use `runas` to execute it as a different user?

Comment: Well there is a second person/customer involved... I have updated my question accordingly. Using `runas` is not an option.